# Airflow PythonVirtualenvOperators access to context datetime

Tags: python, airflow

Basically I need to access to the execution date on a **PythonVirtualenvOperator** and as far as I know you can't pass the execution date as *op_kwargs* or *provide_context=True*. I read that by using pendulum one can achieve this but I haven't seen any useful docs about it. Does anyone knows how to achieve this or has an example that can illustrate this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help other people answer your question, please provide details about what you have tried so far (i.e. your existing code) as well as the expected and actual outputs or any errors you got.

Answer (score 0):

The `provide_context` is deprecated and no longer needed in Airflow 2. PythonVirtualenvOperator derives from `PythonOperator` and you can pass all the variables to it the same way as you would for `PythonOperator`.

You have the very same `context` dictionary passed to it (well, it's a serializable version of it, but datetime fields are serializable) and you can use it in the same way you would use them in `PythonOperator`.